# A sub-variety of the Grassmannian

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, projective-geometry, projective-space

Is there a nice description of the variety $G(3,6) \setminus \sqcup_{i+j=3}(G(i,3) \times G(j,3))$ in terms of blow ups or a sub-variety of a secant variety ? Where the product of Grassmannians $G(i,3) \times G(3-i,3)$ embedded in the bigger Grassmannian $G(3,6)$ naturally.